# Q - Postman: How to clear collectionvariables between tests

Tags: automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing

I'm new to API testing through postman and i'm currently trying to figure out how to clear down my collection variables between automated tests.

Here is my code below - Thanks so much for anybody who can point me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: You can use this for an individual variable `.unset('var_name')` or this to get rid of all of them `.clear()`

Answer (score 5):

Warning :

```
pm.collectionVariables.clear()
```

will delete all your collection variables:

```
pm.collectionVariables.unset("variablename")
```

will delete that particular variable.

so if you just want to reset the value to initial value then:

in the first request add:

```
 pm.environment.get("resetValue") ? null:pm.variables.set("resetValue",pm.collectionVariables.toJSON().values)
```

Here we store data only if resetValue variable is not set

And in the last request:

```
 pm.environment.get("resetValue").forEach((a)=>pm.collectionVariables.set(a.key,a.value))
 pm.environment.unset("resetValue")
```

This make sure you don't set resetValue incorrectly if you are running first request multiple time

you can also use pm.variables if you don't any variable to be affected , thats the better way